# Using for loop variable to access element in array yielding NA in R

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I'm using a nested for loop to create a greedy algorithm in R.

```
z = 0
for (j in 1:length(t))
  for (i in 1:(length(t) - j))
    if ((t[j + i] - t[j]) >= 30)
      {z <- c(z,j + i - 1)
      j <- j + i - 1
      break}
z
```

Where t is a vector such as:

```
 [1]  12.01485  26.94091  33.32458  49.46742  65.07425  76.05700
 [7]  87.11043 100.64116 111.72977 125.72649 139.46460 153.67292
[13] 171.46393 184.54244 201.20850 214.05093 224.16196 237.12485
[19] 251.51753 258.45865 273.95466 285.42704 299.01869 312.35587
[25] 326.26289 339.78724 353.81854 363.15847 378.89307 390.66134
[31] 402.22007 412.86049 424.23181 438.50462 448.88005 462.59917
[37] 473.65289 487.20678 499.80053 509.14141 526.03873 540.17209
[43] 550.69941 565.74602 576.06882 589.07297 598.53208 614.20677
[49] 627.44605 648.08346 665.49614 681.46445 691.01806 704.05762
[55] 714.09172 732.04124 745.90960 758.52628 769.80519 779.41537
[61] 788.35732 805.78547 818.75262 832.71196 844.97859 856.08608
[67] 865.72998 875.55945 887.20862 900.00000
```

The goal for the function is to find the indexes whose differences are as close to 30 as possible and save them in z.

For example, with the vector t provided, I would expect z to be [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10,...70]

The functionality is not my concern right now, as I am running into the error:

```
Error in if ((t[j + i] - t[j]) >= 30) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I'm new to R so I know I'm not utilizing the vectorization that R is known for. I simply want to have 'j' and 'i' as "counter variables" that I can use to access specific elements of vector t, but for a reason unknown to me, the if statement is not yielding a T/F value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post a self-contained, reproducible example.

Comment: there is a specific problem with `:` in R, which is that `1:0` is `[1 0]` (not an empty vector).  More generally; try a fairly short vector (as `t`) and use `cat(i,j,i+j,"\n")` to print indices as you go along to see what's happening

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to learn how to use `for-loop`, but it is difficult to help you because you did not provide a reproducible example. On the other hand, in R a lot of functions were vectorized, meaning that you can avoid `for-loop` to achieve the same task with more efficient ways.

Based on the description in your post "The goal for the function is to find the indexes whose differences are as close to 30 as possible and save them in z." I provided the following example to address your question without a `for-loop`.

```
z <- which.min(abs(diff(vec) - 30))
z
# [1] 49

vec[c(z, z + 1)]
# [1] 627.4461 648.0835
```

Based on the data you provided, the indices with the numbers difference which are the closest to 30 is `49`. The numbers are `627.4461` and `648.0835`.

#### Data

```
vec <- c("12.01485 26.94091 33.32458 49.46742 65.07425 76.05700 87.11043 
         100.64116 111.72977 125.72649 139.46460 153.67292 171.46393 
         184.54244 201.20850 214.05093 224.16196 237.12485 251.51753 
         258.45865 273.95466 285.42704 299.01869 312.35587 326.26289 
         339.78724 353.81854 363.15847 378.89307 390.66134 402.22007 
         412.86049 424.23181 438.50462 448.88005 462.59917 473.65289 
         487.20678 499.80053 509.14141 526.03873 540.17209 550.69941 
         565.74602 576.06882 589.07297 598.53208 614.20677 627.44605 
         648.08346 665.49614 681.46445 691.01806 704.05762 714.09172 
         732.04124 745.90960 758.52628 769.80519 779.41537 788.35732 
         805.78547 818.75262 832.71196 844.97859 856.08608 865.72998 
         875.55945 887.20862 900.00000")

vec <- strsplit(vec, split = " ")[[1]]

vec <- as.numeric(grep("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+", vec, value = TRUE))
```